# Minimum and Sufficient Exercises that can be done at home?

Tags: home-exercise

I want to stay fit and exercise everyday. Anyhow, I do not want to go to a Gym. What are some good exercises that I can do in home without requiring any equipments?

Comment: There's no reason that you need to go to the gym to train or 'stay fit'. What you do need is a set of goals that you want to obtain and then build a plan around those. Are you looking to loose weight? gain strength? gain stamina? get in touch with the inner you? Once you know where you're going you can easily search this site (or google) for fitness routines that will get you there.

Comment: What are your goals? "Staying fit" is very broad. Do you want to look fit, run marathon, lift your bodyweight over your head?

Answer (score 3):

Most health guidelines suggest a minimum of 30 min's of activity at least 5 times a week, to maintain a rudimentary level of fitness. This is for an already healthy adult (18-64) eg.

- [NHS: Physical activity guidelines for adults](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/fitness/Pages/physical-activity-guidelines-for-adults.aspx)
- [American Heart Association Recommendations for Physical Activity in Adults](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/PhysicalActivity/FitnessBasics/American-Heart-Association-Recommendations-for-Physical-Activity-in-Adults_UCM_307976_Article.jsp)
- [WHO: Physical Activity and Adults](http://www.who.int/dietphysicalactivity/factsheet_adults/en/)
- [30 Minutes of Daily Exercise Enough to Shed Pounds](http://www.webmd.com/fitness-exercise/20120824/30-minutes-daily-exercise-shed-pounds)

Though a number of studies show an hour+ at varying exertion levels yields significant health and performance benefits, again for healthy adults. If you look at a number of the associated / suggested programmes, attached to these studies, they'll suggest a mix of exercises, to work different muscle groups, and at different intensities eg.

- Walking, Dancing, Gardening, Hiking, Swimming, Cycling (30+ mins a day)
- Jogging (15+ mins day)
- Planks (5+ mins day)
- Squats (30+ day)
- Push Ups (30+ day)
- Sit Ups (60+ day)
- Jumpin Jacks (30+ day)
- Lunges (30+ day)
- Crunches - Twisting / Bicycle (30+ day)
- Yoga (15+ mins)
  .....

**Note**: These are total daily figures and could be be broken down into small sets, performed throughout the day.

Depending on your existing condition and what you're trying to achieve, I'm fairly sure you'll be able to find a weekly exercise routine and diet regime to suit.

Answer (score -2):

The best you can do is (these 3 will keep you fit and active as well)

```
1. Push ups 
2. Leg raises/crunches (any one)
3. Sit ups
```

Do as much reps as you can do easily in start and than increase reps slowly after every 2 or 3 weeks as comfortable. Don't take much rest during exercise. Do these 5 days a week.